# Can "of all" stand before "best"?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order

Would it be perfectly correct to write "Of all types of cats the black ones are studied best"? I've found such sentences in the internet. On the other hand, they are very few.

Comment: Yes it is, *of all* and *best* have nothing to do with one another here. You could have replaced *of all* with *among all the* and *best* with *the most*, it would have been exactly the same thing.

Comment: Idiomatically, ***best*** is a rather unusual modifier for ***study*** - [has been studied best](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22studied+best%22#tbm=bks&q=%22has+been+studied+best%22) gets just 867 hits in Google Books, but [has been studied **most**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22has+been+studied+most%22) gets 28,500 hits.

Comment: Hm... These definitely are not synonims :(  Thank you.

Comment: For example, "Of all the red wines produced in the Napa Valley of northern California, perhaps the Beaulieu Vineyards' Pinot Noir is the best" is perfectly fine English usage (whether the statement is true or not).

Comment: In your example it is somehow obvious to me. Perhaps because "THE best" doesn't need "Of all..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native speaker here.

> Would it be perfectly correct to write "Of all types of cats the black ones are studied best"?

No. I can infer your meaning, which is either that *black cats make the best subject for research* or that *black cats have been the most studied*, but without clarification it's hard to tell.

Depending on what you're trying to say, the two following examples would be more appropriate:

*Of all the types of cats, black ones are the easiest to study*

*Of all the types of cats, black ones are studied the most*

Even then, the sentence construction for a simple phrase isn't particularly natural; it would be more common to say "black cats are the easiest to study" or "black cats are studied the most", and "of all the types of cats" would be implied. 
I would be more inclined to use the construction in a more complex sentence like the one @Mark Hubbard gave above, where you're really emphasising the exclusiveness of the subject. For example, "of all the books that I have ever read, *Pride and Prejudice* was undoubtedly the best" feels more natural, although that could also be because *best* doesn't often modify *study*, and certainly not in the context you have given.

Comment: Thank you. Your 2nd sentence is exactly what I meant. The last article is quite unexpected to me